# Replace “Add to Cart” button with an “Buy Now” button linking to the “Checkout” page

Tags: magento-1.7

In my Magento site product view page, I need to replace the button "Add to Cart" to "Buy Now" button in I want like to the "Checkout" page.

Example : 
if the customer clicks the "buy now" button the link will going to the checkout page.

[image]

Comment: link to checkout page???

Comment: if any one click the "buy now" button the product  will going to  checkout page.

Comment: Do you want to do add to cart of that product and go to checkout page right?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Buy Now'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the path `app >design>frontend>base>default>template>catalog>product>view`
File  `addtocart.phtml` copy to your theme folder and edit line no. 28 add to cart to buy now thats it

Comment: thank you for your replay but Im try like your way but it's not working. can you tell me please how i can do this please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the addtocart.phtml file inside your current theme, otherwise it will not work

Comment: i already Change the addtocart.phtml file code but it's not working.

Comment: Are you sure you edited the correct file? If you changed the file in the base folder, it will not change anything, you have to change the file in your current theme.

Comment: yes sure. because in my themes don't have this file i copy from base folder. and pest in my  correct  themes

Comment: and don't forget to clear cache

Comment: how to clear cache?

Comment: It's also done but not working

Answer (score 0):

Go to `admin panel -> system configuration -> design` and check to see what the package name and template are. Write this down, and navigate to your theme and do what the others have suggested. Copy the `addtocart.phtml` into `app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/view` and edit it appropriately.

Comment: yes edit same way but it's not working

Comment: under the design tab, what does it say under Current package name and theme-> template

Comment: yes inside view folder addtocart.phtml  right.

Comment: what does the admin panel say? what package are you using?

Comment: sorry what is the meaning of package ? please

Comment: this way to add the file :

app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/view

Comment: no, package/theme are placeholders go to your admin panel to find what the package is

Comment: there have like this "Theme137K "

Comment: then it will be app/design/frontend/Theme137K/theme/template/catalog/product/view, but remember theme is also a placeholder what does it say under template?

Comment: app/design/frontend/default/Theme137K/template/catalog/product/view 

it' will like this

Comment: no what does admin panel say for template? template is under theme

Comment: yes template has under the themes.

Comment: if template is blank then it will be app/design/frontend/default/Theme137K/default/catalog/product/view

Comment: i want put the file like this order or?  if i put like do not affect any other file?

Comment: please help me to slow this problem? please please

Comment: what you posted looks right

Comment: you asking about the images or?

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared the cache?
Go to System>Cache Management> Flush Magento Cache & Flush Cache Storage,
also you can delete the cache folder from your server (/var/cache).

Comment: it's already try this but it's not working. how to delete the cache from server? please tell me how to do that?

Comment: connect to your server with a ftp client like Filezilla and under the root path where you installed magento you have a folder called var and there you will see the cache folder. Just delete it.

Comment: it's also done but not working?

Comment: What have you set under System>Design or System>Configuration>Design>Package,System>Configuration>Design>Themes ?

Comment: in magneto or server?

Comment: In magneto. In System>Design you should have something like packagename/themename or  in the System>Configuration>Design>Package should appear your package name and in the  System>Configuration>Design>Themes should be your themename.

Comment: can click and see the image i have like that.

http://styling.lk:2082/cpsess4792459379/frontend/x3/filemanager/showfile.html?file=error.png&fileop=&dir=%2Fhome%2Fstyling&dirop=&charset=&file_charset=&baseurl=&basedir=

Comment: did you see the image

Comment: I can't see it. The link redirect me to a CPanel login

Comment: how to do this please help me !!..

Comment: the thing is that you must change the addtocart.phtml located under your packagename/theme for this to work. if the file doesn't exist there, check app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view and edit that file. Other method should be to translate it with the csv from the local

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it can help you:

Magento generates an add to cart url for add to cart buttons.

It's in the form of

`http://{YOUR SITE NAME}/checkout/cart/add/uenc/{Base64 Encoded Redirect Url},/product/{PRODUCT ID}/form_key/{FORM KEY}/`

```
$url = strtr(base64_encode($url), '+/=', '-_,'); // for base64 encode

$form_key = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); // for getting form_key
```

if you use `http://{YOUR SITE NAME}/checkout/onepage` as redirect url magento redirect you directly to checkout after product added to cart.

You only have to make a button which redirects to this url. // `onclick=setLocation(url);`